# Usage of wildcard '%' not working for seeing grants of a user from any host

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

Are my queries wrong?.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS for 'root'@'%';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host '%'

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'wp_user'@'%';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'wp_user' on host '%
```

My DB server is MariaDB 10.3.25

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `SHOW GRANTS` works. You need to have a specific user defined by the username and the hostname. You can query the correct users with this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('\'', user, '\'@\'', host, '\'') FROM mysql.user;
```

Comment: Thank you for this.